# Alternative to Html.ValidationMessage

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In a view in MVC 5 I could do something like this to render a textbox and validation for it:

```
@Html.TextBox("Comment")
@Html.ValidationMessage("Comment")
```

If I was binding to a property on the model in a MVC Core View I would do this:

```
<input asp-for="Comment"/>
<span asp-validation-for="Comment"></span>
```

But what is the MVC Core alternative to Html.ValidationMessage to render a validation span tied to an input that's not bound to the model?

Comment: did you ever work this out?

Comment: Just use @Html.ValidationMessage("Comment")   It's valid MVC Core syntax in a cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span asp-validation-for="[yourproperty]"></span>
```

is tied only in your property

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
```

this validation is for the model you could also set asp-validation-summary="All"

Comment: Sorry bub, I'm not asking about rendering the validation summary.